# Most appropriate version of EOS to start

Tags: nodeos, eosio-code

Currently I am running EOS version 1.1.1  for my smart contract, But within a short time so many versions had been released. Before that I was working with 1.0.1 because of some issues I switched to version 1.0.2, Later on I had to upgrade to 1.1.1 within few days.

I know upgradation is a very crucial step in development. But my question is If a beginner want to learn EOS what is the suitable version to start with?

Comment: The latest stable version on the master branch of eosio should always be the recommended version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with 1.07 if you just want to build with it.  That seems to be about where the official docs are at.  Here's a good source for tutorials: https://trybe.one/eos-developers/

Answer (score 2):

You should start with [v1.2.3](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v1.2.3), as it contains important fixes for major bugs with dev tools, like [this](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/5401) problem.

Installed it fresh just today.